# How to parse date such that it is in EST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 3.1. Here is my configuration

```
config.time_zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
```

Now user enters Nov 30, 2011 at 7:00 PM. How do I parse this text so that after parsing I get the result in EST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so by calling `time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new('EST').parse('Nov 30, 2011 at 7:00 PM')`. Also you can parse the time string as being in user-specific or default timezone by calling `Time.zone.parse`. You can convert the result time into any timezone thanm i.e. `Time.zone.now.in_time_zone('Asia/Yekaterinburg')`

Also there is no need in do any manual conversions of timezones before storing the time to database as Rails does is automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should store all values in UTC and render them in user's local time. "Eastern Time" is a loose concept at best and changes on a fairly regular basis as politicians decide to extend or contract Daylight Saving Time.

Generally you can do this with the [ActiveSupport::TimeZone](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html) methods `local_to_utc` and `utc_to_local` conversion methods.